# How to make checkboxes exclusive?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm a beginner with the WinAPI and trying to modify code from someone else, making a pair of checkboxes exclusive which were non-exclusive previously.

My initial try was to uncheck the other immediately if one was checked, but this obviously works in one direction only. If IDC_2 is checked and I try to check IDC_1 it triggers the first 'if' statement again and it fails.

This is the code I have:

```
static WDL_DLGRET dlgProc(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwndDlg, IDC_1)) {

        // do something

        // try to make exclusive 
        CheckDlgButton(hwndDlg, IDC_2, BST_UNCHECKED);
    }

    if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hwndDlg, IDC_2)) {

        // do something

        // try to make exclusive 
        CheckDlgButton(hwndDlg, IDC_1, BST_UNCHECKED);
    }
}
```

I know about radio buttons, but in this case the choices can also be non mutually exclusive. It's possible to have non of the two boxes checked (but not both at once) so I think radio buttons wouldn't be the right choice here, or ?

Comment: Radio buttons are for mutually exclusive choices. If you want a "none of the above" choice, put that option too. IMHO, it's bad UX to use components that don't act like expected.

Comment: Get both states; work out the required state(s) (in code); set both states.  This will lead to unexpected behaviour for the user but will do what you have asked.  Try to find similar controls (in MS Office for example) and see how they implement this sort of change of state (from the users perspective).

Comment: Don't. Checkboxes are not meant to be exclusive. That's radio buttons. Use the right control for the job. When the user sees checkboxes, the user knows that they are independent. When the user sees radio buttons, they know that they are exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions that immediately present themselves

1. Radio buttons but add a third "none" option
2. react to check-box activation (being ticked) and clear out your other check-boxes.

Take option 1.  Principle of least suprise. It is a bad idea to subvert common (well known and functionally accepted) user interfaces.

You could keep the checkboxes if this is a setup that later validates the input, e.g. in a dialog or form that you then submit, but you will need to add a description along the lines of:

> select up to one option below
>   and then perform validation, refusing to accept until a maximum of one are selected.

Just take option 1.

Comment: Option 2 is valid for me, at least if there are only two checkboxes. I use this often, when I have two options that are mutually exclusive. In other words options 1 and 2 can both be unchecked, but option 1 cannot be checked if option 2 is checked and option 2 cannot be checked if option 1 is checked

Comment: @MichaelWalz Yes, it is a valid way of doing it, hence it is in the answer, but for the OP, I would suggest he takes the simpler route, at least for now.

Comment: This answer addresses the part of my question about radio buttons (and UI design principles) which I appreciate but doesn't really answer the question in the title ("How...") i.e. coding related in detail imo (maybe I haven't made this clear enough though) . But since I went with radio buttons now after reading all the comments / replies I'll accept it. Thanks.